# set a text box visible if the "other" checkbox is selected

Tags: javascript

I am trying to set a text box visible if the "other" checkbox is selected

here is the HTML output:

```
 <dx:ASPxCheckBoxList ID="reasons" ClientInstanceName="reasons" runat="server" ClientVisible="false">
    <Items>
    <dx:ListEditItem Text="Location" Value="7" />
    <dx:ListEditItem Text="Other" Value="8" />
    </Items>
    <ClientSideEvents SelectedIndexChanged="function(s, e){ if (reasons.getText()=='Other'){ txtBoxOther.SetVisible(true);}}" />
 </dx:ASPxCheckBoxList>
<br />
```

Please explain why my javascript code is incorrect.

```
    h2>Eligibility</h2>

    <input type="hidden" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$pageControl$eligibility1$hdnID" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_pageControl_eligibility1_hdnID" value="0" />



    <table class="dxeCheckBoxList_Material" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_pageControl_eligibility1_reasons" style="border-collapse:separate;">
                        <tr>
                            <td class="dxe"><input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_pageControl_eligibility1_reasons_VI" type="hidden" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$pageControl$eligibility1$reasons" /><table>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><table class="dxeBase_Material dxeTAR" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_pageControl_eligibility1_reasons_RB0">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="dxichCellSys"><span class="dxWeb_edtCheckBoxUnchecked_Material dxICheckBox_Material dxichSys"><span class="dxKBSW"><input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_pageControl_eligibility1_reasons_RB0_I" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$pageControl$eligibility1$reasons$RB0" value="I" type="text" readonly="readonly" style="opacity:0;width:0;height:0;position:relative;background-color:transparent;display:block;margin:0;padding:0;border-width:0;" /></span>       </span></td><td class="dxichTextCellSys"><label class="dx-wrap">Location</label>    </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table><script id="dxss_1836432940" type="text/javascript">
    <!--
ASPx.AddDisabledItems('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_pageControl_eligibility1_reasons_RB0',[[[''],[''],['']]]);

    //-->
    </script></td>
                                </tr><tr>
                                    <td><table class="dxeBase_Material dxeTAR" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_pageControl_eligibility1_reasons_RB1">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="dxichCellSys"><<input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_pageControl_eligibility1_reasons_RB1_I" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$pageControl$eligibility1$reasons$RB1" value="I" type="text" readonly="readonly" style="opacity:0;width:0;height:0;position:relative;background-color:transparent;display:block;margin:0;padding:0;border-width:0;" /></span>      </span></td><td class="dxichTextCellSys"><label class="dx-wrap">Other</label>   </td>
                                         </tr>
                                     </table><script id="dxss_1704498575" type="text/javascript">
     <!--
ASPx.AddDisabledItems('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_pageControl_eligibility1_reasons_RB1',[[[''],[''],['']]]);

     //-->
     </script></td>
                                </tr>
                            </table></td>
                         </tr>
                      </table><script id="dxss_1417929759" type="text/javascript">
     <!--
    ASPx.AddDisabledItems('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_pageControl_eligibility1_reasons',[[['dxeDisabled_Material'],[''],['','RB0','RB1']]]);

var dxo = new ASPxClientCheckBoxList('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_pageControl_eligibility1_reasons');
dxo.InitGlobalVariable('reasons');
dxo.SetProperties({
    'uniqueID':'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$pageControl$eligibility1$reasons',
    'imageProperties':{
    '4':['dxWeb_edtCheckBoxChecked_Material','dxWeb_edtCheckBoxUnchecked_Material'],
    '8':['dxWeb_edtCheckBoxCheckedDisabled_Material','dxWeb_edtCheckBoxUncheckedDisabled_Material']
},
    'icbFocusedStyle':['dxICBFocused_Material',''],
    'initSelectedIndices':[]
});
dxo.SetEvents({
    'SelectedIndexChanged':function(s, e){ if (reasons.getText()=='Other'){ txtBoxOther.SetVisible(true);}}
});
dxo.InitializeProperties({
    'decorationStyles':[
        {'key':'F','className':'dxeFocused_Material','cssText':''}
    ],
    'items':[['Location','7',''],['Other','8','']]
});
dxo.AfterCreate();

//-->
</script>
<br />
<table>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="dxic" style="width:100%;"><input class="dxeEditArea_Material dxeEditAreaSys" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_pageControl_eligibility1_other_I" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$pageControl$eligibility1$other" onfocus="ASPx.EGotFocus(&#39;ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_pageControl_eligibility1_other&#39;)" onblur="ASPx.ELostFocus(&#39;ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_pageControl_eligibility1_other&#39;)" onchange="ASPx.EValueChanged(&#39;ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_pageControl_eligibility1_other&#39;)" value="Enter Reason" type="text" /></td>
                    </tr>
                </table><script id="dxss_1988614690" type="text/javascript">
<!--
ASPx.AddDisabledItems('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_pageControl_eligibility1_other',[[['dxeDisabled_Material'],[''],['','I']]]);

var dxo = new ASPxClientTextBox('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_pageControl_eligibility1_other');
dxo.InitGlobalVariable('txtBoxOther');

    ]
});
dxo.AfterCreate();

//-->
</script>
```

Please help me find the error in my javascript. it is not allowing me to save my changes with out more detail as this question is mostly code...

Comment: Show the output **html** and not the asp code

Comment: Either tag it with ASP or change it to html.

Comment: Please show some HTML and describe where you are running into problems.

Comment: Please read out how to post questions in stack overflow

Comment: Please read this for guidance on [ask] a good question. Here's a [tour] on how SE works

Comment: im using devexpress controls

Comment: can you pls explain where im going wrong with asking my question

Comment: Instead of the asp.net code, go to the page in a browser, right-click, view-source. This shows you the HTML generated by that ASP. The JavaScript code should be in there, too. If you find that and the HTML and paste it here, we can look at what it does and what the problem could be. With just this, we have no idea how things work in-browser.

Comment: thank you @Whothehellisthat i hope im sending the right thing. i appreciate you helping a newbie!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer to my question:
     function selectedIndexChanged(s, e) {
            var item = reasons.GetSelectedItem();
            if (item.text == 'Other') {
                txtBoxOther.SetVisible(true);